# How to get total items from Paging 3 Android using Kotlin to implement onclicklistener for each item?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-paging-3

I am following this article [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).
All is working well but now I want to implement the onclicklistener for each item.

Here's my code:

SongViewModelAdapter.kt

```
    class SongViewModelAdapter(private val onSelect: ((ViewModelLyric?) -> Unit)?) : PagingDataAdapter<ViewModelLyric,
        SongViewModelAdapter.SongViewHolder>(Companion) {

    val TAG = "SongViewModelAdapter"

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val dataBinding = LyricDataBinding.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return SongViewHolder(dataBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val lyric = getItem(position) ?: return
        holder.bindLyric(lyric, onSelect)
    }

    companion object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ViewModelLyric>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ViewModelLyric, newItem: ViewModelLyric): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ViewModelLyric, newItem: ViewModelLyric): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    inner class SongViewHolder(
        private val dataBinding: LyricDataBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dataBinding.root) {
        fun bindLyric(lyric: ViewModelLyric, onSelect: ((ViewModelLyric?) -> Unit)?) {
            dataBinding.itemTitle.text = lyric.title
            dataBinding.itemArtist.text = lyric.artist

            dataBinding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onSelect?.let { it1 -> it1(lyric) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    val TAG = "HomeFragment"

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentHomeBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeFragmentViewModel>()
    private var adapter = SongViewModelAdapter(null)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = SongViewModelAdapter(::onSelect)
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun onSelect(viewModelLyric: ViewModelLyric?) {
            val id = viewModelLyric?.id

            val bundle = bundleOf("id" to id)

            Log.d(TAG, id.toString())
            view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.songDetailFragment, bundle)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setLyricsAdapter()
        getLyrics()
        setProgressBarAccordingToLoadState()
    }

    private fun setLyricsAdapter() {
        binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun getLyrics() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.flow.collectLatest {
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setProgressBarAccordingToLoadState() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest {
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = it.append is LoadState.Loading
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter at the moment and it works well. For those experienced in paging 3, how would you pass total items to implement the click listener for each item. Saw similar questions but never a clear solution. Been scratching my head for a day. Your help will be much appreciated.

Edit 1: Added HomeFragment.kt

Edit 2: Updated with user suggestions. Click still not working. I needed to add the null checks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to handle click inside your adapter.

The adapter concern is just to act as a bridge b/w our data and the recyclerview not to handle click. Passing it back to fragment/activity restores that. Second, using callbacks may lead to Memory leaks as it going to have the reference to the fragment/activity.

```
class YourRecyclerViewAdapter(private val onSelect: (ViewModelLyric?) -> Unit) : PagingDataAdapter<ViewModelLyric, SongViewModelAdapter.SongViewHolder>(Companion) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val lyric = getItem(position) ?: return
        holder.bindLyric(lyric)
    }

    class SongViewHolder(private val binding: YourViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dataBinding.root) {

        fun bindLyric(yourDataType: ViewModelLyric?, onSelect: (ViewModelLyric?) -> Unit) {
           dataBinding.itemTitle.text = lyric.title
           dataBinding.itemArtist.text = lyric.artist
           dataBinding.root.setOnClickListener {
               onSelect(yourDataType)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

In your Fragment/Activity

```
// Set this adapter to your recycler view
binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = YourRecyclerViewAdapter { viewModelLyric-> 
    // Handle click here
}
```

EDIT:

**SongViewModelAdapter**

```
class SongViewModelAdapter(private val onSelect: (ViewModelLyric) -> Unit) : PagingDataAdapter<ViewModelLyric, SongViewModelAdapter.SongViewHolder>(Companion) {
    
    val TAG = "SongViewModelAdapter"

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val dataBinding = LyricDataBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return SongViewHolder(dataBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val lyric = getItem(position) ?: return
        holder.bindLyric(lyric, onSelect)
    }

    companion object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ViewModelLyric>() {
        
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ViewModelLyric, newItem: ViewModelLyric): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ViewModelLyric, newItem: ViewModelLyric): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    class SongViewHolder(private val dataBinding: LyricDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dataBinding.root) {
        
        fun bindLyric(lyric: ViewModelLyric, onSelect: (ViewModelLyric) -> Unit)) {
            dataBinding.itemTitle.text = lyric.title
            dataBinding.itemArtist.text = lyric.artist
            dataBinding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onSelect(lyric)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    val TAG = "HomeFragment"

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentHomeBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeFragmentViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = SongViewModelAdapter(::onSelect)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        getLyrics()
        setProgressBarAccordingToLoadState()
    }

    private fun onSelect(lyric: ViewModelLyric) {
        // handle click here
    }

    private fun getLyrics() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.flow.collectLatest {
                binding.adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setProgressBarAccordingToLoadState() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest {
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = it.append is LoadState.Loading
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks for taking out the time to answer.

Comment: I tried your solution and the click still wouldn't work. I have updated the post with my HomeFragment file. The click before your solution worked but had no data, now even the click won't work.

Comment: Please check what I'm doing wrong when you have the time, cheers.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer I don't see you using my code?? Your adapter constructor doesn't look like mine?

Comment: @OhhThatVarun forgot to update the post. Made onSelect nullable as I tried calling adapter before then again in the getLyrics() method.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer You don't need the `holder.itemView...` in your `onBindViewHolder`. And you can't pass null to it. Do it as I did. Why you want it nullable?

Comment: I'm talking about the onSelect as I am using the adapter in my HomeFragment class. Check HomeFragment if I am doing it right or wrong.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer commented our part looks good. Look at my answer too.

Comment: Tried it and now I don't get data.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer make this line `onSelect?.let { it1 -> it1(lyric) }` this `onSelect.invoke(lyric)!!` Why you are setting adapter again inside `getLyrics` ??

Comment: Where do I post // Set this adapter to your recycler view
binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = YourRecyclerViewAdapter { viewModelLyric-> 
    // Handle click here
}? Can you please post the full page of HomeFragment.kt how you would do it? Thanks

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer I would do it something like this. Check update.

Comment: Will try it now and let you know. Thanks, mate.

Comment: You removed the adapter from the top and now I can't access it. I've used your suggestions and the click function still doesn't work. I will message you here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231089/discussion-between-thesamoanppprogrammer-and-ohhhthatvarun).

Comment: Updated post with your suggestions, still no luck.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer where are you trying to access it? Access it using `binding.adapter` ?

Comment: binding.productsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter. do I still need this line? Will try without and let you know.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer check updated anaswer.

Comment: Still no luck, thanks for trying to help mate.

Comment: @thesamoanppprogrammer What error you are getting exactly? I'm using this code in production.

Comment: Not getting the data I want. It's always null.

Comment: That's not possible it should crash not show null. `YourRecyclerViewAdapter { viewModelLyric-> 
    // Handle click here
}` here `viewModelLyric` is not null, so it can't be null, check your code.